# Trello: How to change card ID

Tags: trello

I am manually importing from a CSV file (since Trello does not support automatic import from JIRA or YouTrack) the problem I have now is that I need to edit the card number (Card #) to reflect the JIRA issue ID or youtrack issue ID.

Answer (score -2):

According to Trello API you are **not** able to change nor insert your ID.